# How can I preview an image in its original size?

Tags: macos, mac, preview, graphics, image-editing

I have 2 images in a directory and I see from the `Get Info` that one has `Dimensions: 532 × 1051` and size 45KB on disk. The other based on the `Get Info` has `Dimensions: 1440 × 2900` and size 379KB on disk.

#### Problem

When I open them with `Preview` they both show in the same size although the resolution is better in the latter, but how can I preview them and have the images open in their original size? I think the one with `532 × 1051` should be smaller when opened.

I see that there is an option in `Preview -> View -> Actual Size`, I selected that but the size remained the same (slightly zoomed in) and now that option is grayed out.

Answer (score 4):

"Resolution" is not the number of pixels, but the number of pixels per inch, or centimeter, or other unit.

Most image formats contain data about the resolution: i.e. how many image pixels should appear in a given screen area. If the smaller image has a resolution of 72 pixels per inch, and the larger image a resolution of c. 200 ppi, then they will appear the same size on screen in Preview.

You can see the DPI setting for an image in Preview by showing the Inspector window -- `Command I`. If the image file has a resolution set, it will be listed there as DPI Height and DPI Width.

Preview does have a Preference to define 100% scale as either 1 image pixel = 1 screen pixel, or to use the resolution data in the image ("size on printout").

Comment: `how many image pixels should appear in a given screen area.` how can I see that?

Comment: `If the smaller image has a resolution of 72 pixels per inch, and the larger image a resolution of c. 200 ppi, then they will appear the same size on screen in Preview` why? 72 < 200

Comment: I did change in the `Preferences` to select `Size on screen equals size on printout` but the size remained the same

Comment: @Jim Yes, the 200 ppi image (with more pixels) puts more pixels in the same space than the 72 ppi one (with fewer pixels). (200 per inch versus 72.) I'll ad more to my answer about finding the DPI.

Comment: When I press `command+I` the `Get Info` opens. I don't see any more info. Also I don't see something that says "Inspector"

Comment: look under the tools menu item. At the top is a menu item that reads Show Inspector.

Comment: @jmh: I found it! It says `96 pixels/inch` for the image of 45KB and `72 pixels/inch` for the image of 380KB

Comment: @Jim The smaller image should be 14 x 29 cm; the larger one should be 50 x 102 cm. You can of course still zoom the images in Preview. Make sure they're both 100%.

Comment: @benwiggy: On preview they both appear the same size though. Also how did you come up with theses sizes?

Comment: A meter by a half meter seems like a huge image...

Comment: I plugged the numbers into Photoshop. But basic maths: 2900 pixels / 96 pixels per inch gives 30.2 inches. And you've clicked on "Actual Size" in the View menu?

Comment: @benwiggy: Yes. Btw `50 x 102 cm`? That is not right obviously. 102cm is  > 1m

Comment: @Jim 2900 is a lot of pixels. If they are indeed set to 72 pixels per inch, then that's going to be a lot f inches. If you don't think your image is that big, then either the pixel count or the resolution must be inaccurate.